# Swift +hide or remove a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have `UITableViewController`, on top of it I placed an `UIView` and inside it there is a `UICollectionView`.

When collectionView data is empty I want to remove the `UIView`. I tried:

```
self.collectionView.removeFromSuperview()
```

and

```
self.collectionView.hidden = true
```

These removes the `UIView` but there is an empty space above my `tableview`. How can I get rid of it?

Edit: added a photo of my storyboard. Recommended View is not inside the tableviewheader.

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the collection view is a table header view (the way you have positioned it in the storyboard).

Try setting it to nil if data is empty

`self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but this code should solve your problem.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.isHidden = true
```

Comment: My view is not inside a header view

Answer (score 0):

You have placed Recommended View inside the table view - not on top of it. So you could have placed it as header or cell. So when you don't want it to be present, change cell pr header height.

Answer (score 0):

The RecommendedView is a `tableHeaderView`. Try to have a outlet to the height constraint of the RecommendedView.

Set the height constraint to 0 in case you don't have any element in the collection view.

```
@IBOutlet var tableHeaderHeighConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    if collectionIsEmpty(){
        tableHeaderHeighConstraint.constant = 0
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```